# How can I get the specific part from the link using regular expressions (regex),,,

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, nsregularexpression

The format of Url is - **https://example.com/items/html5-templates/654321**

1. Firstly I want to take the link **without last numbers.**
   e.g: https://example.com/items/html5-templates/

And,

2. Secondly, want to take **only the last part** (numbers) from the link.
   **e.g: 654321**

**I need to get the regex code** for using in a auto Parse plugin to my wp site,,,

And then I can customise the link as
Like:

> https://.....(link without last part)...../...**anything**..../...(only last numbers from the link format)...

***Thanks a lot for your precious time,,,***

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I don't know. Because  I'm using a third-party auto Parse plugin to parge product from another site to my wp site. But in this plugin supported these regex like [^0-9] to get numbers and </?a(|\s+[^>]+)> to avoid links from content. Which are written as find / replace rule  into the plugin,,, But, at this time, I want to know about the above questions I specified. Thanks for sharing your surprising experiences,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/J25BXr/2):

```
^(.*/)(\d+)$
```

The first part of URL will be in first capture group, and second capture group will be numbers.

Comment: This can work but remember to escape `/`  `^(.*\/)(\d+)$`

Comment: depends on the language.  Some enclose regular expressions in`/` which then must be escaped within the regular expression, but some don't.

Answer (score 1):

use str.replace(/\/\d+$/, '') to remove /86886866 from string like https://www.wexperts.xyz/32423
The result will be like https://www.wexperts.xyz